# Can't login to GUI with my Valid password

Tags: gui

I have ubuntu server 12.10 and installed ubuntu-desktop to access it via GUI and changed the default runlevel to 5. Now I get the GUI login screen with my username (display name) but when i enter my password the screen just flicks and comes back to login screen ( doesnt give me any error). the same user works fine with same credentials in CLI.

strange thing is when i click on guest, it logs me in straight away and works fine.

Any solution please.

PS: I am new to Ubuntu/linux, Keeping in mind, please be basic and simple.

Answer (score 10):

This looks like the .Xauthority file is corrupted. Try this in a tty:

```
sudo mv .Xauthority .Xauthority_backup
```

Then restart lightdm and try to log in again:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

If that was not the cause, restore the file to its previous state:

```
sudo mv .Xauthority_backup .Xauthority
```

Comment: Hi darent. thankyou for your reply but unfortunately No success with it..

Comment: Yes , this was the problem and it worked ..thanks for sharing...

Comment: wow!!! This is a terrible user experience!!! wondering how many gurus we need around just to be able to log into a linux distro. thanks for the fix!